# Should we create a tag for geological risks?

Tags: feature-request

They are sometimes associated to volcanoes, sometimes to earthquakes, sometimes to landslides, sometimes to tsunamis...

I have had teachers that were experts in this subject and wrote complete books about it.

Should we create the tag?

Comment: I am not against such a tag, it could be useful. If such a tag were created, the definition of geological risk would need to be clearly defined. It's a term that could have different meanings to different people.